# Attach div with display inline block with last word for wrapping

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

is it possible just with pure css to attach last two divs inside span with its last word so it would wrap with the last word? Even when you dynamically resize window?

Here is html :

```
<span>Some text that will be here
    <div class="class1" style=""></div>
    <div class="class2"></div>
</span>
```

Here is css :

```
.class1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    background-image: url(some.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.class2 {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background: url(some2.png) -154px 0px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want the span to wrap only with the use of last word when i try to resize the window. What happens now is that it first wrap the class2 div, then class1 div and after then it starts to wrap the text. Ive seen many solutions using just display:inline but when i use display:inline on the divs it losts it width so i dont think its a possible solution here. Is there any way with pure css solution to attach those two divs with last word of the text so it wraps together when you resize the window? I cant encapsulate last word with those two divs inside another element like this :

```
<span>Some text that will be 
    <span class="encaps">here
        <div class="class1" style=""></div>
        <div class="class2"></div>
    </span>
</span>
```

Because the text is always different length and i dont know before what the last word will be.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

**UPDATE**

I am writing down some examples of behaviour that i want to accomplish when the window is resizing:

```
Bad behaviour:

1.)
Some text will be here*div*
*div*
2.) 
Some text will be here
*div**div*

Good behaviour:

Some text will be 
here*div**div*
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of what you have. might be easier to see it in action

Comment: `span` elements cannot contain `div`. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: Nesting of `div` inside of `span` Was invalid in HTML4.01 - HTML5 removed the destinction between inline and block elements - [See MDN's details on inline/block elements here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all of the text in a span and then allow line breaks inside that span, but not between it and the divs. You will need to apply that styling to the container span. This works as follows.

Note that I made some very minor changes to your example (changed divs in spans into spans to make the HTML valid, changed image URLs so they resolve to something, minor style changes), but the main idea is the styling of the `.wrap` and `.nowrap` elements. The `.wrap` element is an added element, a `span` wrapping the text.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Justastudent/dd9ezjdx/1/) as well, so it is easier to change the viewport size and test the wrapping.

```css
.class1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/19');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.class2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: url('https://placehold.it/20') no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* no line breaking */
  font-size: 0;
  /* hide text between text and divs */
}

.wrap {
  white-space: normal;
  /* allow line breaks in span */
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* normal font size */
}
```

```html
<span class="nowrap">
  <span class="wrap">Some text that will be here</span>
  <span class="class1"></span>
  <span class="class2"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: @Just a student Hello, thank you for your answer but this doesnt attach those divs to the last words. Both divs wrap after text simultaneously, thats good but the last word still stays on the same line as the rest of the text. It should wrap with those two divs when thez go to the new line. Im sorry that I didnt make it clear enough what I wanted. I will update my question with the proper examples. Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: @Redrif It seems to work for me in Firefox and Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Justastudent Hi i tried it chrome and firefox and it doesnt work like that when i try to resize the window dynamically. First goes those two divs to the new line and after that goes that last word. Its not at the same time. I mean try to resize your exact JSFiddle example to size 660px. You will see that only those two divs are in the new line. I updated the JSFiddle here to show you https://jsfiddle.net/dd9ezjdx/2/. I want to attach the last word so it goes to the new line the exact time when those two divs go to the new line.

Comment: @Redrif That is very strange indeed and should not happen. Unfortunately, I really [cannot](http://imgh.us/so-215.png) [reproduce](http://imgh.us/so-216.png) the issue. Looking at what the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#propdef-white-space) says, I don't see any reason why a break would occur between the text and images. I'm unsure of how I can help you further debugging this :-(

Comment: @Justastudent can i ask what OS are you using? Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: @Redrif Chrome on Windows [doesn't](http://imgh.us/so-220.png) [work](http://imgh.us/so-221.png) indeed. Let me try to fix this.

Comment: @Redrif Right, I cannot seem to get it to work in Chrome on Windows. It seems a bug to me, but I'm not sure... It may also be possible to work around this problem, but I have not found a way to do so. Sorry...

Comment: @Justastudent Its ok, thank you very much for you help so far :-) I will try to fix this myself on chrome.